# Vue: How to call a function within a sibling component?

Tags: vue.js

I have an app that has a Parent component (app.js) and 2 child sibling components ( Modal.vue and Cart.vue).

I am getting a response back from a call within Modal.vue that needs to trigger a function within Cart.vue right after. What are the best options of going about this?
I don't currently use Vuex, which I know would make this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `refs` like so:

```
<parent>
 <modal @triggerFunc="triggerFunc"/>
 <cart ref="$cartRef"/>
</parent>

...
triggerFunc(){
   this.$refs.$cartRef.functionIwantToTrigger()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an event bus:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) for this using the `root` Vue instance of the current component tree.

**In Modal.vue:**

Where you are getting a response back from a call, simply emit a custom event like:

```
this.$root.$emit('onupdate', data);
```

**In Cart.vue:**

Simply listen to this root emitted event like

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {},
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('onupdate', data => {
      // trigger a function within Cart.vue
      this.myFunction(data)
    });
  }
  methods: {
    myFunction: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
})
```